# Java Program to output the contents of a file within a range of numbers

Tags: java, arrays

So basically, my problem is, I have a text file with 5000 values in it. I am supposed to figure out how to display only the values within the range (there's no set range, but I've chosen between 1000 and 1500. So, all numbers between those values should be found and output to a text file named "User Name".txt.

The main dilemma is, I'm not able to have the text file in the code. I need it to be handled as a command line arg, and I've never really dealt with this type of problem before.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestProg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int LowerBound = 0;
        int UpperBound = 0;

        String Name1 = null;
        String Name2 = null;

        //instantiates the array to read in the numbers from the file
        double[] FileNums = new double[5000]; 
        //instantiates the array to output the upper and lower bounded values.
        double[] OutputNums = new double[5000]; 

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("This program will output the upper or lower
                            bounds of the text file.
                            Please input which lower bound you would like.");
        LowerBound = scanner1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Now input the upper bound."); 
        UpperBound = scanner1.nextInt();

        Names(Name1, Name2);
    }

    public static String Names(String Name1, String Name2) {
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input your first name.");
        Name1 = scanner2.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Now input your last name.");
        Name2 = scanner2.nextLine();
    }
}
```

I'm basically stuck with how to start. I believe it would involve a while loop in order to tell the program to only find the values in the range, but I'm not entirely sure.

I also have another minor problem where Name1 and Name2 keep reverting back to null since I have the names being input in a separate method.

Any help would be wonderfully appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The command line args are stored in the argument `args` of your main method. How to read text from a file is described in the Java IO tutorial. Have you read it?

Comment: You might want to consider showing an example of the source file. You mentioned there are numbers in there but how exactly do they look like?

Comment: Hello! Just an offtopic quick note for future code, try to make it comply with the Java Naming Conventions that are out there that specify naming patterns for pretty much everything you can manipulate the name of in java with the purpose of making code easier to read and understand. For example variable names (except constant variables) must be named as follows: First letter is always lower case and then every word following starts with a capital letter: `aVariableName, someVariable, thisIsAVariable`

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to print number within given range(min, max inclusive).

```
File output = new File("output.txt");
File file = new File("input.txt");
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
        file));
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
bin.read(buffer);
String fileStr = new String(buffer);
String[] numbers = fileStr.split("\\s");

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter min number in range");
int rangeMin = s.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter max number in range");
int rangeMax = s.nextInt();

for (String number : numbers) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(number) >= rangeMin
            && Integer.parseInt(number) <= rangeMax) {
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(number));
    }
}

bin.close();
```

Input given in input.txt using space as delimeter:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ...
```